# Types as the Core of the Programming Languages

Tags: type-theory

Why theoreticians consider 'types' as the core part of the programming languages?

Comment: I'm not sure about your background, so allow me to give two quick and simple reasons as a comment: (a) "data type" is a far better specified notion than "programming paradigm": you may raise all controversy you want with the latter, but you can already do math with the former; (b) types are ubiquitous and fundamental: the same data types are to be found in principle in all programming paradigms, while the other way around doesn't even make sense.

Comment: (By the way, you might want to try this question in some other se forum.)

Comment: @Basil To avoid any controversy I edited to a single and strait forward question.

Comment: Okay, but to be honest I'm not even sure how "the core part" of pl should be construed (note the definite article!). Note that I didn't say that *your* question was controversial, just that it's often the case that people fight over ill-defined paradigms. You might want to read Harper's post [here](https://existentialtype.wordpress.com/2013/07/18/what-if-anything-is-a-declarative-language/), on declarative languages.

Comment: I think this question is more suitable for [https://cs.stackexchange.com/](https://cs.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Virtually every programming language employs types in some form or
other. Some languages use types only at run-time or only at compile-time,
but hybrids are also widespread.  Program specification and
verification often uses types. The fruitful connection between
programming languages and logic (Curry-Howard correspondence), which has led to technology transfer between both fields, is based on types. Many interesting
algorithmic questions arise from type-checking and type-inference.

All of the above are empirical evidence that types should be a core part of the study of programming languages.